# Uploading to the Web with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web, upload

```html
<div id="xe-editor-container-1" class="input_area xpress_xeditor_editing_area_container" style="height: 400px;">
 <iframe id="editor_iframe_1" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" src="http://my_URL.or.kr/xe/modules/editor/styles/default/editor.html" scrolling="yes" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="editor.css">
      <title>XpressEngine</title>
      </head>
      <body class="xe_content editable"></body>
      </html>   
 </iframe>
 <textarea id="xpress-editor-1" rows="8" cols="42" style="display: none; width: 100%;"></textarea>
 <textarea rows="8" cols="42" class="input_syntax " style="display:none"></textarea>
</div>
```

I want to copy two tables, ListObjects ("Tbl1") on Sheet1, ListObjects ("Tbl2") on Sheet2, and upload them as a single post on the web.

The range of the table can be changed every time.

Logging in to the web, navigating to the bulletin board, pressing the write button and typing the title succeeded.

But I have failed to upload the post.

Perhaps you can not find the bulletin board object.

Code I created by searching the web.

The HTML above is the board's HTML code.

```
With ie
    .navigate "http://my_URL/offering"
    ieBusy ie   'Procedure fetched as search (check the ready status)

    .Document.getElementsByClassName("ico_16px write")(0).Click
    ieBusy ie

    Dim oTitle As Object, Ocontents As Object

    Set oTitle = .Document.getElementsByname("title")(0)   'Sometimes fail(sometimes Nothing)
    Set oContents = .Document.getElementsByClassName("xe_content editable")(0) 'evry time fail(=Nothing)

    oTitle.Value = "my Title"
    oContents.Value = ????
    .Document.forms(0).submit   'I could not confirm it because it did not work anymore.

End With
```

```vb
Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

---

title HTML

[image]

board HTML

[image]

Comment: You need a proper wait condition before this line: Set oTitle = .Document.getElementsByname("title")(0)  if it is sometimes working and sometimes not.  I can't see your proc ieBusy.  So first try putting this before it While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend . You can also try a timed loop to set the element : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334183/6241235   Please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html, not images of html.

Comment: I added the HTML code and the ieBusy procedure. Thank you.

Comment: So try adding an additional timed loop to set the element oTitle as in link I shared above.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use an additional timed loop to set `oTitle` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334183/6241235

2) Your `oContents`  variable is selecting for an element which is inside an iframe I think. I would expect you to instead be targeting a textarea element. There are two that come after the iframe. The first has id `xpress-editor-1`

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function AES_Encrypt(plainText As String, key As String) As String
    Dim keyBytes() As Byte, plainTextBytes() As Byte, cipherTextBytes() As Byte
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, round As Long, state(3, 3) As Byte, roundKey(3, 3) As Byte
    
    ' Convert key and plaintext to byte arrays
    keyBytes = StrConv(key, vbFromUnicode)
    plainTextBytes = StrConv(plainText, vbFromUnicode)
    
    ' Pad plaintext to multiple of 16 bytes
    Dim paddedTextBytes() As Byte
    ReDim paddedTextBytes((Len(plainText) \ 16 + 1) * 16 - 1)
    For i = 0 To Len(plainText) - 1
        paddedTextBytes(i) = plainTextBytes(i)
    Next i
    
    ' Initialize state with plaintext
    For i = 0 To 3
        For j = 0 To 3
            state(i, j) = paddedTextBytes(i + j * 4)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Generate round keys
    Dim expandedKey(15, 3) As Byte
    AES_ExpandKey keyBytes, expandedKey
    For round = 0 To 9
        For i = 0 To 3
            For j = 0 To 3
                roundKey(i, j) = expandedKey(round * 4 + j, i)
            Next j
        Next i
        
        ' Perform AES round
        AES_SubBytes state, True
        AES_ShiftRows state, True
        If round < 9 Then
            AES_MixColumns state, True
        End If
        AES_AddRoundKey state, roundKey
    Next round
    
    ' Convert cipherTextBytes back to string
    ReDim cipherTextBytes(UBound(paddedTextBytes))
    For i = 0 To 3
        For j = 0 To 3
            cipherTextBytes(i + j * 4) = state(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    AES_Encrypt = StrConv(cipherTextBytes, vbUnicode)
End Function

Private Sub AES_ExpandKey(keyBytes() As Byte, expandedKey(,) As Byte)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, temp(3) As Byte
    
    ' Copy key into first 4 columns of expanded key
    For i = 0 To 3
        For j = 0 To 3
            expandedKey(i, j) = keyBytes(i + j * 4)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Generate remaining columns of expanded key
    For i = 4 To 43
        For j = 0 To 3
            temp(j) = expandedKey(i - 1, j)
        Next j
        
        If i Mod 4 = 0 Then
            AES_RotWord temp
            AES_SubWord temp
            temp(0) = temp(0) Xor AES_Rcon(i \ 4)
        ElseIf i Mod 4 = 4 Then
            AES_SubWord temp
        End If
        
        For j = 0 To 3
            expandedKey(i, j) = expandedKey(i - 4, j) Xor temp(j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Function
Private Sub AES_RotWord(ByRef word() As Byte)
    Dim temp As Byte
    temp = word(0)
    word(0) = word(1)
    word(1) = word(2)
    word(2) = word(3)
    word(3) = temp
End Sub

Private Sub AES_SubWord(ByRef word() As Byte)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 3
        word(i) = AES_Sbox(word(i))
    Next i
End Sub

Private Function AES_Rcon(ByVal round As Integer) As Byte
    Dim result As Byte
    If round = 1 Then
        result = 1
    ElseIf round > 1 Then
        result = AES_xtime(AES_Rcon(round - 1))
    End If
    AES_Rcon = result
End Function

Private Function AES_xtime(ByVal b As Byte) As Byte
    Dim result As Byte
    If (b And &H80) = &H80 Then
        result = (b << 1) Xor &H1B
    Else
        result = b << 1
    End If
    AES_xtime = result
End Function

Private Function AES_Sbox(ByVal b As Byte) As Byte
    AES_Sbox = AES_SboxTable(b)
End Function

Private Function AES_SboxTable(ByVal index As Byte) As Byte
    Dim result As Byte
    result = AES_Sbox(index)
    AES_SboxTable = result
End Function

Private Const AES_Sbox(256) As Byte = {
    &H63, &H7C, &H77, &H7B, &HF2, &H6B, &H6F, &HC5, &H30, &H01, &H67, &H2B, &HFE, &HD7, &HAB, &H76,
    &HCA, &H82, &HC9, &H7D, &HFA, &H59, &H47, &HF0, &HAD, &HD4, &HA2, &HAF, &H9C, &HA4, &H72, &HC0,
    &HB7, &HFD, &H93, &H26, &H36, &H3F, &HF7, &HCC, &H34, &HA5, &HE5, &HF1, &H71, &HD8, &H31, &H15,
    &H04, &HC7, &H23, &HC3, &H18, &H96, &H05, &H9A, &H07, &H12, &H80, &HE2, &HEB, &H27, &HB2, &H75,
    &H09, &H83, &H2C, &H1A, &H1B, &H6E, &H5A, &HA0, &H52, &H3B, &HD6, &HB3, &H29, &HE3, &H2F, &H84,
    &H53, &HD1, &H00, &HED, &H20, &HFC, &HB1, &H5B, &H6A, &HCB, &HBE, &H39, &H4A, &H4C, &H58, &HCF,
    &HD0, &HEF, &HAA, &HFB, &H43, &H4D, &H33, &H85, &H45, &HF9, &H02, &H7F, &H50, &H3C, &H9F, &HA8,
    &H51, &HA3, &H40, &H8F, &H92, &H9D, &H38, &HF5, &HBC, &HB6, &HDA, &H21, &H10, &HFF, &HF3, &HD2,
    &HCD, &HC1, &H1C, &H53, &HBB, &H16, &H66, &HCC, &HAD, &H03, &H4B, &HF6, &H95, &H6D, &HFF, &H30,
    &HE0, &H8B, &H57, &H60, &H46, &HB4, &H6E, &HCB, &H1E, &H9F, &HCA, &H3D, &HAF, &H37, &H08, &HFB,
    &H43, &H4F, &H2C, &H52, &H16, &HFC, &H0B, &H91, &H1F, &H12, &H80, &HE2,&HEB, &H27, &HB2, &H75,
    &H09, &H83, &H2C, &H1A, &H1B, &H6E, &H5A, &HA0, &H52, &H3B, &HD6, &HB3, &H29, &HE3, &H2F, &H84,
    &H53, &HD1, &H00, &HED, &H20, &HFC, &HB1, &H5B, &H6A, &HCB, &HBE, &H39, &H4A, &H4C, &H58, &HCF,
    &HD0, &HEF, &HAA, &HFB, &H43, &H4D, &H33, &H85, &H45, &HF9, &H02, &H7F, &H50, &H3C, &H9F, &HA8,
    &H51, &HA3, &H40, &H8F, &H92, &H9D, &H38, &HF5, &HBC, &HB6, &HDA, &H21, &H10, &HFF, &HF3, &HD2,
    &HCD, &H0C, &H13, &HEC, &H5F, &H97, &H44, &H17, &HC4, &HA7, &H7E, &H3D, &H64, &H5D, &H19, &H73,
    &H60, &H81, &H4F, &HDC, &H22, &H2A, &H90, &H88, &H46, &HEE, &HB8, &H14, &HDE, &H5E, &H0B, &HDB,
    &HE0, &H32, &H3A, &H0A, &H49, &H06, &H24, &H5C, &HC2, &HD3, &HAC, &H62, &H91, &H95, &HE4, &H79,
    &HE7, &HC8, &H37, &H6D, &H8D, &HD5, &H4E, &HA9, &H6C, &H56, &HF4, &HEA, &H65, &H7A, &HAE, &H08,
    &HBA, &H78, &H25, &H2E, &H1C, &HA6, &HB4, &HC6, &HE8, &HDD, &H74, &H1F, &H4B, &HBD, &H8B, &H8A,
    &H70, &H3E, &HB5, &H66, &H48, &H03, &HFF
                                                }

Private Sub KeyExpansion(ByVal key() As Byte, ByRef expandedKey() As Byte)
Dim bytesPerWord As Integer = 4 ' AES-128 uses 4 bytes per word
Dim expandedKeySize As Integer = 176 ' AES-128 uses 176 bytes for key expansion
ReDim expandedKey(expandedKeySize - 1) ' allocate space for the expanded key
' copy the original key into the expanded key
For i As Integer = 0 To 15
    expandedKey(i) = key(i)
Next

Dim currentWord(bytesPerWord - 1) As Byte ' stores the current word being processed
Dim tempWord(bytesPerWord - 1) As Byte ' used for temporary storage during key expansion

' iterate over each 4-byte word in the expanded key, starting from the 4th word
For i As Integer = 4 To (expandedKeySize / bytesPerWord) - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To bytesPerWord - 1
        currentWord(j) = expandedKey((i - 1) * bytesPerWord + j)
    Next

    ' perform key schedule core
    If i Mod 4 = 0 Then
        ' rotate the current word
        tempWord(0) = AES_Sbox(currentWord(1))
        tempWord(1) = AES_Sbox(currentWord(2))
        tempWord(2) = AES_Sbox(currentWord(3))
        tempWord(3) = AES_Sbox(currentWord(0))

        ' apply the Rcon value to the first byte of the word
        tempWord(0) = tempWord(0) Xor AES_Rcon(i / 4)
    Else
        ' copy the current word
        tempWord(0) = currentWord(0)
        tempWord(1) = currentWord(1)
        tempWord(2) = currentWord(2)
        tempWord(3) = currentWord(3)
    End If

    ' xor the current word with the word 4 bytes before it
    tempWord(0) = tempWord(0) Xor expandedKey((i - 4) * bytesPerWord)
    tempWord(1) = tempWord(1) Xor expandedKey((i - 4) * bytesPerWord + 1)
    tempWord(2) = tempWord(2) Xor expandedKey((i - 4) * bytesPerWord + 2)
    tempWord(3) = tempWord(3) Xor expandedKey((i - 4) * bytesPerWord + 3)

    ' copy the temporary word into the expanded key
    For j As Integer = 0 To bytesPerWord - 1
        expandedKey(i * bytesPerWord + j) = tempWord(j)
    Next
Next
End Sub

Private Sub AES_AddRoundKey(ByRef state(,) As Byte, roundKey(,) As Byte)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = 0 To 3
        For j = 0 To 3
            state(i, j) = state(i, j) Xor roundKey(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Function

Private Sub AES_SubBytes(ByRef state(,) As Byte, Optional ByVal inverse As Boolean = False)
    Dim sBox(255) As Byte, i As Long, j As Long
    
    ' Initialize sBox with forward or inverse S-Box values
    If Inverse Then
        For i = 0 To 255
            sBox(i) = AES_InvSBox(i)
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 0 To 255
            sBox(i) = AES_Sbox(i)
        Next i
    End If
    
    ' Substitute bytes in state with sBox values
    For i = 0 To 3
        For j = 0 To 3
            state(i, j) = sBox(state(i, j))
        Next j
    Next i
End Function

Private Sub AES_ShiftRows(ByRef state(,) As Byte, Optional ByVal inverse As Boolean = False)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp(3) As Byte
    
    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 0 To 3
            temp(j) = state(i, (j + i) Mod 4)
        Next j
        
        For j = 0 To 3
            state(i, j) = temp(j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Function

Private Sub AES_MixColumns(ByRef state(,) As Byte, Optional ByVal inverse As Boolean = False)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp(3) As Byte
    
    For j = 0 To 3
        For i = 0 To 3
            temp(i) = state(i, j)
        Next i
        
        If Inverse Then
            state(0, j) = AES_GFMul(0x0e, temp(0)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x0b, temp(1)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x0d, temp(2)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x09, temp(3))
            state(1, j) = AES_GFMul(0x09, temp(0)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x0e, temp(1)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x0b, temp(2)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x0d, temp(3))
            state(2, j) = AES_GFMul(0x0d, temp(0)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x09, temp(1)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x0e, temp(2)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x0b, temp(3))
            state(3, j) = AES_GFMul(0x0b, temp(0)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x0d, temp(1)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x09, temp(2)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x0e, temp(3))
           Else
            state(0, j) = AES_GFMul(0x02, temp(0)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x03, temp(1)) Xor temp(2) Xor temp(3)
            state(1, j) = temp(0) Xor AES_GFMul(0x02, temp(1)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x03, temp(2)) Xor temp(3)
            state(2, j) = temp(0) Xor temp(1) Xor AES_GFMul(0x02, temp(2)) Xor AES_GFMul(0x03, temp(3))
            state(3, j) = AES_GFMul(0x03, temp(0)) Xor temp(1) Xor temp(2) Xor AES_GFMul(0x02, temp(3))
        End If
    Next j
End Function

Private Sub AES_ShiftRows(ByRef state(,) As Byte, Optional ByVal inverse As Boolean = False)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, shift As Long, temp As Byte
    
    For i = 1 To 3
        If Inverse Then
            shift = 4 - i
        Else
            shift = i
        End If
        
        For j = 0 To shift - 1
            temp = state(i, 0)
            
            For k = 1 To 3
                state(i, k - 1) = state(i, k)
            Next k
            
            state(i, 3) = temp
        Next j
    Next i
End Function

Private Sub AES_SubBytes(ByRef state(,) As Byte, Optional ByVal inverse As Boolean = False)
    Dim sBox(255) As Byte, i As Long, j As Long
    
    ' Initialize sBox with forward or inverse S-Box values
    If Inverse Then
        For i = 0 To 255
            sBox(i) = AES_InvSBox(i)
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 0 To 255
            sBox(i) = AES_Sbox(i)
        Next i
    End If
    
    ' Substitute bytes in state with sBox values
    For i = 0 To 3
        For j = 0 To 3
            state(i, j) = sBox(state(i, j))
        Next j
    Next i
End Function

Public Sub Main()
    Dim plainText As String, key As String, encryptedText As String
    
    ' Get input from user
    plainText = InputBox("Enter plaintext to encrypt:", "AES Encryption")
    key = InputBox("Enter encryption key (16 characters):", "AES Encryption")
    
    ' Encrypt plaintext
    encryptedText = AES_Encrypt(plainText, key)
    
    ' Display encrypted text
    MsgBox "Encrypted Text: " & encryptedText, vbInformation, "AES Encryption"
End Sub
```